# Why does npm install packages in different directories?

Tags: npm

I have several projects that use a common core code base. That core is in a subdirectory and defines it's own npm dependencies. In the projects I would like to install project specific npm packages as well as the dependencies of the core, which looks like this:

**./package.json**

```json
{
  "dependencies": {
    "core": "file:./core",
    "es6-promise": "~4.2.2",
    "url-search-params-polyfill": "^2.0.3"
  }
}
```

When I run `npm install` all the packages from `./package.json` and `./core/package.json` are installed but two strange things happen:

1. Some packages are installed in `./core/node_modules` instead of `./node_modules`
2. This works only on a fresh install. If the `package-lock.json` is already there the following error gets thrown:

   ```
   npm ERR! path /proj/core/node_modules/jest-cli/node_modules/node-notifier
   npm ERR! code ENOENT
   npm ERR! errno -2
   npm ERR! syscall rename
   npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename '/proj/core/node_modules/jest-cli/node_modules/node-notifier' -> '/proj/core/node_modules/jest-cli/node_modules/.node-notifier.DELETE'
   npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
   ```

Removing the lock file helps, but is a bad solution. The versions I run are: node 8.11, npm 5.6.0

I would like to know why npm behaves that way, installing in two different directories. Understanding that would solve the other one as well, I think.