# Why the same package are installed in a different way?

Tags: javascript, node-modules, yarnpkg

I installed the same package for both my projects. That package(won't link, it's private one) has react-popper as dependency(which in order has create-react-context as dependency), so, when I run project one - everything is ok, but error appears for project two:

> ERROR in ./node_modules/react-popper/lib/esm/Manager.js
>   Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'create-react-context' in '/../node_modules/react-popper/lib/esm'

After some investigation, I got that node_modules structure is different:

- for project one, all react-popper dependencies are saved in project one
  node modules, and local folder contain only warning package:
  [image]
- for project two all react-popper dependencies saved in ../react-popper/node_modules local folder:

[image]

I've tried some common approaches like reinstalling node modules, clear cache and so on, but the structure is the same. Actually I had a thoughts about webpack and babel versions, but I don't think it can affect node_modules structure itself.

So the question is, which factors can affect it? What should I check?

**NOTE**: If I manually add create-react-context to project two, it works fine, but it's not a solution.

**NOTE**: I found out similar issue, but no suggestions there - [Why does npm install packages in different directories?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50597380/why-does-npm-install-packages-in-different-directories), im my case re-creating of yarn.lock also helps, but it's also doesn't look like a right way to solve it. Hope my description is more complete and will help to figure it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is very likely because of the way yarn (as well as npm) tries to [deduplicate](https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/dedupe) dependencies. Let's say there are modules A and B which exist in 2 versions (1.0.0 and 2.0.0). B depends on Version 1.0.0 of Module A.

If you install only module B, you will get a node_modules folder like this:

```
node_modules
- A@1.0.0
- B@2.0.0
```

But what if you install module A in its latest version (2.0.0)? If npm just updated the version of module A, your existing module B would (potentially) no longer work as it depends on module A. So your node_modules folder will instead look like this (A@1.0.0 is moved inside B's node_modules folder)

```
node_modules
- A@2.0.0
- B@2.0.0
-- A@1.0.0
```

Your 2 projects likely have further dependencies, which somehow overlap with react-popper or its dependencies. Due to the nodeJs module resolution mechanism, this usually shouldn't be a problem.

TLDR: The exact structure of the node_modules folder depends on all your dependencies (and devDependencies). yarn/npm will look into every package.json/package-lock.json file of your projects dependencies (and their dependencies) and use this information to calculate a dependency tree with minimal duplication.

Comment: Very informative. In our case, create-react-context package is not installed in global directory, despite it using only in react-popper. I bet there is some problem in our lock file. Thanks.